# How to make this script grep only the 1st line

Tags: bash, grep, xargs

```
for i in USER; do
    find /home/$i/public_html/ -type f -iname '*.php' \
    | xargs grep -A1 -l 'GLOBALS\|preg_replace\|array_diff_ukey\|gzuncompress\|gzinflate\|post_var\|sF=\|qV=\|_REQUEST'
done
```

Its ignoring the -A1.  The end result is I just want it to show me files that contain any of matching words but only on the first line of the script. If there is a better more efficient less resource intensive way that would be great as well as this will be ran on very large shared servers.

Comment: As described in http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Context-Line-Control, `-A1` has nothing to do with restricting what lines to test. It's for printing additional output after each match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code is untested:

```
for i in USER; do
    find /home/$i/public_html/ -type f -iname '*.php' | while read -r; do
        head -n1 "$REPLY" | grep -q 'GLOBALS\|preg_replace\|array_diff_ukey\|gzuncompress\|gzinflate\|post_var\|sF=\|qV=\|_REQUEST' \
            && echo "$REPLY"
    done
done
```

The idea is to loop over each `find` result, explicitly test the first line, and print the filename if a match was found. I don't like it though because it feels so clunky.

Answer (score 1):

Use `awk` instead:

```
for i in USER; do
    find /home/$i/public_html/ -type f -iname '*.php' -exec \
     awk 'FNR == 1 && /GLOBALS|preg_replace|array_diff_ukey|gzuncompress|gzinflate|post_var|sF=|qV=|_REQUEST/
          { print FILENAME }' {} +
done
```

This will print the current input file if the first line matches. It's not ideal, since it will read all of each file. If your version of `awk` supports it, you can use

```
awk '/GLOBALS|.../ { print FILENAME } {nextfile}'
```

The `nextfile` command will execute for the first line, effectively skipping the rest of the file after `awk` tests if it matches the regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
for j in (find /home/$i/public_html/ -type f -iname '*.php'); 
    do result=$(head -1l $j| grep $stuff ); 
    [[ x$result |= x ]] && echo  "$j: $result"; 
done
```

You'll need a little more effort to skip leasing blank lines. Fgrep will save resources.
A little perl would bring great improvement, but it's hard to type it on a phone.

Edit:
On a less cramped keyboard, inserted less brief solution.

Comment: How do you add `head` to the `find`/`xargs` pipeline above? And how do you preserve the filename for `grep -l`?

Comment: Yeah I am not sure:

         `code`for i in USER; do find /home/$i/public_html/ -type f -iname '*.php' | xargs head -1l |grep -B1 'sF=\|qV=' ; done`code`